# Question on modules over algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be an algebra over a commutative ring $R$ and let $A$ be projective as a module over $R$. Let $M$ be a right $A$-module, that is, $M$ is an abelian group with a right action of $A$. This right action induces a (right) $R$-module structure on $M$ via $m.r=m.(r.1_A)$ where $1_A$ is the unit of the algebra.

My question is: In the setting above, is $M$ automatically projective as a right module over $R$?

Comment: No since $A=R$ and $M$ not projective provides a counterexample

Comment: That's true thanks for that remark. So I should ask for $M$ to be $A$-projective at least. This case is dealt with in egreg's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $M$ is projective as $A$-module, then it is a direct summand of $A^{(I)}$ (as $A$-modules). On the other hand, $A$ is a direct summand of $R^{(J)}$ (as $R$-modules).

Now $A^{(I)}$ is a direct summand of $(R^{(J)})^{(I)}\cong R^{(J\times I)}$ as $R$-modules.

Thus, if $M$ is projective as $A$-module, it is also projective as $R$-module. The converse is not true, in general: as an easy counterexample take $A=R$ and any non projective $R$-module.

Notation: $X^{(I)}$ is the direct sum of $I$ copies of $X$.

Comment: Could you explain your notation $A^{(I)}$ and why $M$ is a direct summand of that? The other part of your answer I understand.

Comment: @user291910 It's the direct sum of copies of $A$ (a free module, in this case).